# How can humanity prepare after predicting the dissapearance of the sun?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, survival

Somehow, in 2018 humanity discovers that the sun will vanish in exactly a hundred years time. This event **will not** cause damage to the various objects of the solar system, the sun will simply implode onto itself and disappear as if it went into a different dimension.

How can the world start building in **anticipation** of the sun's departure? Through what methods could humanity continue to **survive** without the presence of the sun (ie none of its light/heat)? How (if even possible) could the various species of the Earth that depend on sunlight be preserved? Could humans perhaps **relocate** to another star system?

Comment: "Will they ... " sounds like you are asking us to pick a storyline for you. You can write a story about them building giant space ships (there are a lot of story like this), or building some structures to keep Earth livable (I don't know a story like this. Will be very interesting).

Comment: I'd rather you ask "What kind of structures that will allow human to keep inhabit earth when the sun dies?"

Comment: If this happens, then seven or eight decades of stellar astrophysics is wrong. Given the bundles of evidence *against* such a scenario, you're going to raise a few eyebrows.

Comment: Is the earth going to be intact? Because bunkers would be way easier to build and stock than spaceships. It's not like the spaceships will have anywhere to go since without the sun, nothing that we can reach in a million years would be remotely habitable.

Comment: @hde maybe it's not the models that were wrong but the data fed to it. Let's say there's a supernova explosion at 100ly away and evidence suggests an unusually large hunk of deadly plasma is coming at us at 0.5c? Or perhaps a stray "bullet" from a star war that's happened a long long time ago in a galaxy far away (though determining when exactly that arrives might be tricky)?

Comment: @JohnDvorak If there's wrong data, people are *probably* going to say that it's the data saying that the Sun's going to die. The result's going to be disputed . . . and so aside from some doomsday cults, most people are just going to reject the idea.

Comment: Will the gravitational attraction of the sun still be present once it disappears? Normally I'd assume the answer to be **no** but I feel like you haven't thought through all the implications of the sun's disappearance and perhaps you don't want to have a story about the earth departing from its previous orbit.

Comment: May I recommend everyone put paper bags over their head or something?  "Will it help?" "Well, no"

Comment: Short answer (a comment because answers aren't allowed any more) is that humans CAN'T survive for any length of time.  A relative few might survive for a while, if they had stockpiles of food & fuel.  As for the general reaction, aren't we experiencing something quite similar right now?  Global warming is likely to render the Earth uninhabitable to humans in a few centuries, yet most people either ignore it (after all, they don't expect to live that long), or deny the science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The most realistic scenario is, of course, denial

No one will believe the "predictions" - and why should they? They run counter to 200 years of observational astronomy as well as the Laws of Physics. Your simplistic meme that "humanity" does anything in some uniform, consistent, or coherent way is sadly detached from reality.

I don't understand - at all - what you mean by stating that the Sun's disappearance will not "cause damage". Makes no sense. Do you mean it won't change daytime heating? Do you mean it won't damage crops? Do you mean it won't freeze our atmosphere? Do you mean it won't change the orbits of every single object in the solar system? That is nonsense.

The most likely way we could survive as a technological species is to go underground. We'll have plenty of water, and enough air to last for thousands of years and we might even be able to make our ecology nearly self-sustaining (using nuclear power, oil, coal, etc.).

I have no idea what size population we could save this way, but suspect we'd be lucky if more than 1 in 1000 could be saved. I also suspect the chance of nuclear war would increase dramatically: everyone would be willing to fight and die for resources and radioactive fall-out would only be a very temporary problem.

I think the most reasonable approach, assuming you could get any First World government to do anything, would be to immediately start such a underground civilization, adding to it over time as construction proceeded. It's not at all clear to me that democracies could implement this, it requires a two-caste system (the survivors and the doomed), but why not? Less plausible things have been done.

Colony ships are so far beyond our current capabilities as to not merit any serious consideration. Two other possibilities exist:

1. Evolving into silicon based "life" forms.
2. Colonization of the other solar system bodies capable of supporting us (such as under-ice colonies on Enceladus).

There are two other projects (aside from those mentioned above) which I'd pour resources into: Fusion power research and DNA/species modification. I think the reasons for both are self-evident (we should also do more with alternative nuclear power cycles and research into recycling, obviously).

And maybe one more thing: I'd probably spend a bit more both on sending (EMR) signals to our galactic neighborhood (SOS comes to mind) and blasting into space more "golden records" (like on Voyager) - like shouts in the dark that *We Were Here*.

Comment: Interesting, I recognize your username and the style of your answer (no paragraphs and a bit rambling), but your picture chaniged. Pretty sure I've said that a couple of times already, but [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) and [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous).

Comment: I mean, your stuff is not bad. Why make it so hard to read? And why not give everyone the chance to check out more stuff from you by taking a look at your profile? Why not start collecting reputation so you can start to vote yourself or comment on posts other than your own? Anyway, it's nice that you are trying to share your knowledge and I do hope you keep that up, but *please* try to format your answers at least *a little bit*.

Answer (score 3):

When we lost the sun, we didn't just loose the light and heat, we also lost the gravity which kept all the planet on their safe, predictable courses.

Humanity was up for the challenge of the lost light and heat.  We had plenty of warning that it was coming, so we mastered fusion, created shelters and were prepared to handle it when the oceans froze.  When the atmosphere outside the shelters condensed into a liquid slurry, it provided our world with new and frigid ocean.  ...and flash froze the billions of humans, animals and plants who didn't have a warm place to stay.

Those few thousands of us who survived, now harvest the air we need from those seas, and grow our food under artificial light, and we are slowly expanding,  hollowing the earth's crust in search of geothermic heat and room to grow.

We have hope, but it is a hard hope.  And we do our best not to think about what is happening up there, outside.

Because our scientists have shared with us, that in the absence of the Sun, Jupiter is becoming the gravitational center of a new, much smaller solar system.  Many of the planets and asteroids have escaped its pull but we are apparently not going to be one of them.  Just bad luck that the Earth's forward momentum was oriented to intersect with the path of Jupiter's momentum when both planets were freed from the Sun.

We are now headed toward our new solar mistress, to find our place among the complex nest of orbiting objects which already circle her great mass.  Lets just keep our fingers crossed that nothing currently occupies our spot in this new arrangement.

We have survived loosing our old bright sun, but we may not survive finding this new dark one.

Comment: I do not think Earth could be captured in this way.  The relative orbital velocities are huge and the orbits are at different inclinations.  I do not see how we could ever end up close enough to be captured by Jupiter.  Note that at their "optimal" starting positions, Earth would be traveling with a minimum relative speed of the order of $17000ms^{-1}$ we would need to approach within $876km$ to be captured (that's inside Jupiter !).

Comment: @StephenG, My goal with this answer was to illuminate that once the sun's gravity ends, currently impossible collisions become (at least slightly) more possible.  I am happy to get rid of the Jupiter as new solar mistress aspect, but could you confirm the collision issue.  If earth started a straight-line course from any point on its orbit, would it potentially his something?  Like maybe while passing through the asteroid belt or the ort cloud?  Or is space so empty that freezing to death would be our only real problem?

Comment: Every object in the solar system would scatter.  There is no way they could collect in a "new, much smaller solar system".  Some collisions may be possible, the speed of objects orbiting close to the sun is much greater than object orbiting further away.  But, the chances of hitting something serious is *really* low.  Take the night sky, then pick a random point.  The probability that that point is black is the same as the earth's chance of getting out untouched.  Once the earth is past the ort cloud, the probability drops to zero.

Answer (score 2):

*I started writing this answer before "No planet or moon will be damaged..." became part of the question, so it doesn't really answer the question as it now stands.  But much of what it says is still relevant, so I am leaving it as is.*

Some will see it as a liberation.  Barring a major medical advance, no one old enough to read the bad news is going to live long enough see the show.  Even the youngest newborns will have long and hopefully happy lives before end.  We would be free of our responsibility to future generations.  Free to hunt the last elephants, take up cliff diving and pollute to our hearts content.  A life long party and you don't have to clean up when its over.  The sun will take care of the mess.

Others would see it as a challenge.  The would launch hundreds of deep space probes, each carrying a gene pool for our planet, with each genetic sample somehow defended from genetic decay.  These probes would do what we could not.  Venture out in search of intelligent life in the hopes that they would resurrect our species.

Many of the powerful would see this as an opportunity.  With visions of massive generation ships full of humanity's finest (chosen by them of course), they would impose astronomical taxes upon the masses.  Enslaving all of humanity in their last-ditch (and thereby somehow justified) attempt to save the human race. 
The largest and cruelest empires in human history would likely rise to the face the challenge, then just as likely perish in global warfare with each other over who should be in charge.

For most, life would go on as normal.  Living day to day on a paycheck which almost pays the bills, they would enjoy what joy they could while the reaper slowly wanders their way.

Answer (score 1):

There will be absolutely no way to save most of the humanity. But there will be a sure way for some people to survive for years in underground bunkers.

Initially, there will be some chaos with lot of disbelief. Some governments would start large scale efforts to build shelters, some will do nothing, some will just fail because of rising chaos.

Sending any kind of interstellar ark would be out of question, 100 years is not enough reach this level of technology. What can be done is sending AI-guided ship with frozen embryos. This ship will take thousands of years to travel even to the nearest stars, and once there, there would be a chance to seed any suitable planets with life.

But this "seeding" ship would still be very expensive. Major countries need to keep their focus for decades on this project, while social conditions on Earth will continue to deteriorate.

There will be two types of shelters. "Small" shelter would be able to keep people alive for some time for as long as supplies last. "Large" shelter would be a deeply buried "biodome" that can derive its energy from long term source like geothermal energy.

"Large" shelters could be constructed only by governments or very rich individuals. As time would be getting close to the "doomsday", people would try to do everything to get into these shelters. Some would accept the inevitable and ignore the shelters, but still there will be much more people than those shelters can accommodate.

On doomsday itself there will be all sort of apocalyptic events in the society (I believe you've seen enough movies?). Providing that Sun will go out quietly, there wouldn't be much of a show. Just a sudden nightfall, without moon or planets.

Temperatures will begin dropping, but not very quickly. It will take a few days before water will freeze in warmer regions. Ocean will get covered with ice, but underneath the ice conditions are still going to be palatable. In a month, all continents will be enveloped in deep winter, and conditions would become too harsh for surface travel (think Antarctica).

In two months, live will remain only underground and under the thickening ice. It will take years for the oceans to freeze to the bottom, and still there will be liquid water near volcanic spots. By that time, most small shelters will cease to operate, but large shelters should still be Ok. Barring any bad luck, those shelters should be able to maintain life for hundreds of thousands and even millions of years.

Answer (score 0):

As the question has changed I will aslo leave this as it is

I suppose it depends on what sort of explosion you are talking about. The classic exploding star is a supernova, but if the sun exploded via a super nova then there is nothing much we could do except pray.

The surface of the earth would be boiled away at hundreds of meters per second. Even the outer planets would be destroyed with distant Pluto heated to temperatures hotter than the surface of the Sun.

Fortunately the sun is not massive enough to become a supernova so it’s not something we need to worry about.

If there was some other sort of stellar explosion, then things might turn out differently depending on what actually happened. But the very words "sun explodes" do not bode well for humanity at any level.

ref: https://futurism.com/what-would-happen-if-the-sun-went-supernova-2/

Comment: "No planet or moon will be damaged after the sun blows up." I'm assuming OP is looking for ways humanity could survive without the sun (ie no light/no heat).

Comment: @AngelPray Bingo! Man, you saved the day.

Comment: @JohnDvorak LOL! yes indeed thanks - I have corrected it