# How possible is it that a moon in another star system could be habitable?

Tags: planets, space, space-travel, moons, space-colonization

Realistically, is it possible for a moon, say one orbiting around a gas giant in a stars habitable zone, to be habitable fit to colonize? As in habitable to the point it is like or a close twin of Earth like in sci-fi shows p, movies and books etc. Assume it is large and stays in the habitable zone like it's parent planet.

Comment: You want the EXACT probability, to the tenth place?

Comment: No. Just wanted to know if it's possible if one such moon could exist and how.

Comment: And I guess how possible so yes and no

Comment: I was being sarcastic. There is just no way to compute the odds, since none has ever been proven.

Answer (score 1):

None of us can say with any certainty what is waiting for us out there, but if such a moon did exist, it would probably have to rival Earth's mass in order to hold onto it's nitrogen/oxygen atmosphere.

That probably means that the gas giant it is orbiting is massive.  I recently suggested in [an answer to another question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95400/how-can-humanity-prepare-after-predicting-the-dissapearance-of-the-sun/95416#95416) that the Earth might fall into orbit of Jupiter, and the feedback I got from some of our more knowledgeable members stated clearly that Jupiter isn't nearly big enough to hold something Earth size above its own atmosphere.

So you have a earth size planet circling something significantly larger than our Jupiter.  It would probably have a pretty strange day/night cycle because for half of each of its orbit of the gas giant, it would be in total darkness, constantly blocked from the system's sun.  Then during the other have of each orbit, day and night would proceed as we know them, being caused by the rotation of the globe we are standing on.

There would probably also be some really spectacular twilights and sun rises at each transition into the gas giant's shadow.

Pretty cool place... in more ways than one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it certainly is possible. There is no physical reason why an earth sized moon should not orbit a Jupiter sized planet. Although it might be considered unlikely to occur by normal planetary evolution there are ways for such a situation to occur, an earth type planet might have been ejected from its orbit by a larger body moving close to it and it might have been captured by the Jupiter sized body as a moon.

A planet can become up to 15 times the mass of Jupiter before fusion reactions turn it into a brown dwarf “star”. So a larger planet would also help.

https://www.universetoday.com/13757/how-big-do-planets-get/

And if the Earth like moon were in an inclined or even polar orbit (possible if it had been ejected from a previous orbit) then there need not be an serious effects of shadow by the parent planet.